# How do I jump into another menu without nesting unnecessarily?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I'm stuck with the following code and what I'm trying to achieve now, is to NOT nest switches/if statements any further, which would result in ugly code, I assume. To visualize my intention:

```
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyE = Console.ReadKey();
            if (keyE.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && iMOP == 1){
                //Jump to character creation (but not nest this if statement even further)
            {
```

I want to apply this idea to a solved problem which I have already asked before:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            int iMOP = 1;

            Console.WriteLine(" >>New Game");
            Console.WriteLine("   Load Game");
            Console.WriteLine("   Exit Game");

            while (iMOP != 5)
            {
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        iMOP--;
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        iMOP++;
                    }
                }

                if (iMOP == 0)
                {
                    iMOP = 3;
                }
                else if (iMOP == 4)
                {
                    iMOP = 1;
                }

                switch (iMOP)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(" >>New Game");
                        Console.WriteLine("   Load Game");
                        Console.WriteLine("   Exit Game");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("   New Game");
                        Console.WriteLine(" >>Load Game");
                        Console.WriteLine("   Exit Game");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("   New Game");
                        Console.WriteLine("   Load Game");
                        Console.WriteLine(" >>Exit Game");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The questions would be: How do I realize this? Are there decent tutorials which you could link me to?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *Jump to character creation* ? We have no idea what is character creation here.

Comment: //Jump to character creation is just an example (I haven't written that out yet), beforehand I'd need to know how to instance another menu, which I can simply access via the first code block I've added.

Comment: I think the OP wants an `ncurses` implementation in C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any console "graphics" library for .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984487/is-there-any-console-graphics-library-for-net)

Comment: @Aron What do you mean?

Comment: @FoX did you even click on the link?

Comment: @Aron I do not intend to write or use a graphics engine or library in such means. My plan is a purely text-based rpg as console application to learn on.

Comment: @FoX seriously. Click the link, include the library. Its what you want. You want a Console based Graphics engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is going to get too complicated, use a Console based Graphics engine ([Is there any console "graphics" library for .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984487/is-there-any-console-graphics-library-for-net)).
**MonoCurses** seem to be very friendly: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/monocurses/

But, just for curiosity, something much simpler (from scratch):
Use Classes to Create, Display and Get the user input for your menu.

## How it works

It is basically a **Menu** Class, that displays its **MenuItem** classes, and draw while wait the user select a option.
This menu class was then inserted in a nested Switch, for the Main Menu levels.

I tried to do something better, needs refactoring, so you can have some idea to improve:

## Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication22
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
                #region Main Menu
                var m = new Menu() { Title = "MAIN MENU" };
                m.Menus.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "New Game", SelectedForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green });
                m.Menus.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "Load Game" });
                m.Menus.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "Exit Game", SelectedForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow });
                var result = m.ShowAndWaitUserInput();
                //Console.Write("selected was:" + result);
                //Console.ReadLine();
                #endregion

                switch (result)
                {
                    case 0:
                        #region // Jump to character creation
                        var m1 = new Menu() { Title = "CHARACTER CREATION" };
                        m1.Menus.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "New Character" });
                        m1.Menus.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "Load Character" });
                        m1.Menus.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "Return" });
                        var result1 = m1.ShowAndWaitUserInput();
                        switch (result1)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                #region // CREATE THE NEW CHARACTER
                                Console.WriteLine("CREATE THE NEW CHARACTER");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                #endregion
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                #region // LOAD CHARACTER
                                Console.WriteLine("LOAD CHARACTER");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                // Write your code here...
                                #endregion
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                #region // DO ALMOST NOTHING: RETURNS TO PREVIOUS MENU
                                #endregion
                                break;
                        }
                        #endregion
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        #region // Load Game code...
                        Console.WriteLine("LOAD GAME");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        // Write your code here...
                        #endregion
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        #region // EXIT GAME
                        #endregion
                        return;
                }

            } while (true); // Main Menu
        }
    }

    public class MenuItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ConsoleColor SelectedForegroundColor { get; set; }
        public MenuItem()
        {
            this.SelectedForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        }
    }
    public class Menu
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<MenuItem> Menus { get; set; }
        public Menu()
        {
            this.Menus = new List<MenuItem>();
        }

        public int ShowAndWaitUserInput()
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            int selectedMenu = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                #region Display Menu and Sub-Menus
                {
                    var i = 0;
                    // more at http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/~westin/misc/windows_charmap.html
                    Console.WriteLine(" ╔═══════════════════════════════════════════╗");
                    Console.WriteLine(" ║ ░ " + this.Title.ToUpper().PadRight(40).Substring(0, 40) + "║");
                    Console.WriteLine(" ╚═══════════════════════════════════════════╝");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    //var old_CB = Console.BackgroundColor;
                    var old_CF = Console.ForegroundColor;

                    foreach (var menu in Menus)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("   New Game");
                        if (i == selectedMenu)
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = menu.SelectedForegroundColor;
                            Console.Write("  >> ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = old_CF;
                            Console.Write("     ");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(menu.Title);

                        i++;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("");

                    //Console.BackgroundColor = old_CB;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = old_CF;
                }
                #endregion
                #region Get User Input
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        selectedMenu--;
                        if (selectedMenu < 0) selectedMenu = Menus.Count() - 1;
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        selectedMenu++;
                        if (selectedMenu == Menus.Count()) selectedMenu = 0;
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        return selectedMenu;
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            } while (true);
        }

    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This is helping me a great deal. I think I've found the direction now I'll need to head for.

Comment: Now that is fancy in my eyes! Do you have any tutorials in that context you could link me to which contrast everything you did there, at least partially?

Comment: In Visual Studio, collapse all the Regions: it can give a simpler overall look, and understanding.

Comment: Is there a way I can message you in private about smaller questions ? I don't really want to bother the whole community here with that. =/

Comment: You can send me e-mail. But even smaller code questions can be posted on this site as well.